# How can I split a netcdf file based on the value of a field?

Tags: split, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf file (data.nc) containing an emission dataset with several fields (lon, lat, emissions_category, pollutant). The emission category ranges from 1 to 13. So I want to generate 13 netcdf files (one for each category).

How I could do that in CDO or NCO?

Answer (score 2):

This selects the data by index (not value):

```
ncks -d emissions_category,0 data.nc cat0.nc
ncks -d emissions_category,1 data.nc cat1.nc
...
ncks -d emissions_category,12 data.nc cat12.nc
```